# how to make a build of vue js project independent of where it is uploaded?

Tags: docker, vuejs3

I have project with **Vuejs**.

If I build it for this **baseUrl** `'/'`

it will not work when it is uploaded in `'/example-url'`

so every time that I want to upload my project in different **URL** I have to make a **new** build for that ,

and it is **waste** of time

so the question is How I can get a build of project that will work **every where** that is uploaded,

for example : `www.example.com` or  `www.example.com/some-route`

I mean a **general** build is **possible** ?

can **Docker** help about that ?

Comment: try to change base url to `./`

Comment: @ffx14 you mean if i set baseUrl ./ it will work for both / and /example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ffx14 said

I did set **base url** like this and it works for every **path** .

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({

  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ?  './'
    : '/',
})
```